# ¿Cómo conectar con una API en Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, api

Buenas. Necesito que mi aplicación Android conecte con una API para mostrar sus datos, pero no sé cómo se hace. Por ahora estoy intentando crear objetos a partir de lo que se extrae de la API. Tengo el siguiente código que me da error de null al conectar con la API de DC Comics:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String url = "http://dcdatabase.me/characters.json";
    List<Personajes> listaPersonajes = new ArrayList<>(); //inicializamos la lista donde almacenaremos los objetos

    JSONObject object = null; //Creamos un objeto JSON a partir de la cadena
    try {
        object = new JSONObject(url);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JSONArray json_array = object.optJSONArray("Personajes");

    for (int i = 0; i < json_array.length(); i++) {
        try {
            listaPersonajes.add(new Personajes(json_array.getJSONObject(i))); //creamos un objeto Personaje y lo insertamos en la lista
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Gracias.

Comment: Esta URL `http://dcdatabase.me/characters.json` no funciona. Lo primero sería usar un URL que responda. Yo usaría `Volley`  para la petición.

Answer (score 0):

Las conexiones desde Android hay que hacerlas con un método llamado AsycTask, aquí te dejo un ejemplo mio con la meteorología.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final static String url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=hanoi&mode=xml";
private TextView location, country, temperature, humidity, pressure;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    location = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);
    country = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.country);
    temperature = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temperature);
    humidity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.humidity);
    pressure = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pressure);

    new GetWeatherDataTask(this, url).execute();
}

public void callBackData(String[] result) {
    temperature.setText((Float.parseFloat(result[2]) - 273) + " degree Celcius" );
    humidity.setText(result[0] + " %");
    pressure.setText(result[1] + " hPa");
    country.setText(result[4]);
    location.setText(result[3]);
}

}
```

GetWeatherDataTask (el AsynxTask):

```
public class GetWeatherDataTask extends AsyncTask<String[], Void, String[]> {

    private MainActivity activity;
    private String url;
    private XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    public GetWeatherDataTask(MainActivity activity, String url) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        pDialog.setTitle("Get Weather Information from XML");
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String[]... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(this.url);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser myParser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();

            myParser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
            myParser.setInput(stream, null);
            String[] result = parseXML(myParser);
            stream.close();

            return result;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("AsyncTask", "exception");
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String[] parseXML(XmlPullParser myParser) {

        int event;
        String text = null;
        String[] result = new String[5];

        try {
            event = myParser.getEventType();
            while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String name = myParser.getName();

                switch (event) {
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                        text = myParser.getText();
                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                        //get country name
                        if (name.equals("country")) {
                            result[4] = text;
                        } else if (name.equals("humidity")) { //get humidity
                            result[0] = myParser.getAttributeValue(null, "value");

                        } else if (name.equals("pressure")) { //get pressure
                            result[1] = myParser.getAttributeValue(null, "value");

                        } else if (name.equals("temperature")) { //get temperature
                            result[2] = myParser.getAttributeValue(null, "value");

                        } else if (name.equals("coord")) { //get location
                            result[3] = "(" + myParser.getAttributeValue(null, "lat") + " , "
                                    + myParser.getAttributeValue(null, "lon") + ")";
                        }
                        break;
                }
                event = myParser.next();
            }
            return result;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        //call back data to main thread
        pDialog.dismiss();
        activity.callBackData(result);

    }

}
```

Espero que esto te ayude!

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza *Volley* y genera un método:

Donde *Collection* es el nombre de *Json*, `employee.getString("id")` esta el atributo que quieres obtener tal cual esta escrito en el *Json* y el `append()` mostrara el atributo parseado del *Json* almacenado en la variable donde lo almacenaste.

```
 private void jsonParse()
 {
      //URL del API
      String url = "URL";
      
      JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                          //"Collection" nombre del Json
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("Collection");
                            
                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject employee = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                     //almacenas en una variable el atributo del Json que necesitas
                                String id = employee.getString("id");
                    //imprimes la variable
                                textView.append("\nNombre: "+ id);

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        mQueue.add(request);                        
 }
```

Comment: Puedes copiar y pegar este metodo y solo cambiar la URL, Collection y los atributos del Json que quieras